# generic method in a non-generic class

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to create a simple data access class which acts as a library to return various entities. All my entity classes are generated via the Linq-to-SQL mapper in VS 2013, and all of them can be returned from the dataContext via Find(primary id)

I'd like to just define generic Find, Delete, Update etc without having to repeat it for every table/object but I don't want to create a Repository pattern.

How do I create a generic method that works regardless? This is what I have and of course it says T not defined, but I thought we could create generic methods in non-generic classes, so what am I doing wrong?

What I'd like to do is something like

```
var c = DAL<Customer>.Find(id)

var e = DAL<Employee>.Find(id)
```

... etc.

The code I attempted to write is

```
public class DAL
    {
        private string _key;
        private DataContext _context = null;
        //private DbSet<T> _table = null;


        public DAL(string key)
        {
            _key = key;
            _context = new DataContext();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }


        public DbSet<T> Find<T>(int id)
        {
            var d = _context.Set<T>();
            //return d.Find(id);
        }
    }
```

I'm kind of lost... I do not want to define

```
public class DAL<T> where T:class
```

which ties each DAL to a type

This is the first time I'm venturing into generic nethods so any help appreciated

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC or linq, editing tags...

Comment: Why?? Why?? var c = DAL<Customer>.Find(id) = In linq a simple Db.Customers.Single(c=>c.id == ?); What is the benefit of your DAL?

Comment: @Pleun I hear your anguish, I will be doing a bit more than just access (for e.g. employing some caching etc., some centralized code) and if it's not making much sense I have no qualms killing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a generic method of a class, but you will need to use a constraint:

```
public class DAL
{
    // .... previously written code
    public DbSet<T> Find<T>(int id) where T : class
    {
        return _context.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

You will also have to call it like this:

```
var dal = new DAL();
var data = dal.Find<Customer>(1);
```

Also note, that your code has a number of problems, you define a dispose method, but you don't implement the IDisposable interface, you're not actually returning anything from the method, etc..

Note: for all intents and purposes, this is still a repository pattern.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My remaining code isn't done yet, I was just trying to get this specific concept nailed before I went deeper into my code.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
public T Find<T>(int id) where T : class
{
    return context.Set<T>().Find(id);
}
```